# Need help with running terminal commands on startup

Tags: boot, reboot

I made my Zero into a radio transmitter and I am trying to make it transmit on startup, I am not quite sure how to do it, I've looked around different forums but I can't really find anything. I would appreciate it very much if someone would like to help me with this. I am running a lite version of raspbian.

What I want it to do is to open the directory and run the program with a command.

Directory:

`radio/fm_transmitter-master/`

The command I want it to type out in the directory:

`sudo ./fm_transmitter -f 104.0 -r song.wav`

I have tried to do something myself in `crontab -e` and `rc.local` but I've had no succes.

Please do reply if you know what I can do.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the command `sudo crontab -e` and make cron start a bash file that contains your `fm_transmitter -f 104.0 -r song.wav`.

So make a bash file like `/home/pi/fm_transmitter -f 104.0 -r song.wav` and let crontab run that.